# Request to a public Google Form returns Access Denied: HTTP

Tags: excel, vba, google-forms

I am trying to use MS Excel to automate the filling up of the Google Form, but I have problem with access, the same code was working before and I did not change anything. here is the code:

```
Sub postGoogleData()
Dim params As String, url As String

url = "https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/d/e/1FAIpQLSejadFloQF5V69ZZ1fc1kManOZ_vMw8kq10-56ENroZ4c6xiw/formResponse"
params = "entry.1880992192=<NAME>&entry.2125520249=<IG>&entry.1421191722=<E>&entry.1858469755=Option+1&entry.1858469755=Option+2&dlut=1632409237551&entry.1858469755_sentinel=&fvv=1&draftResponse=%5Bnull%2Cnull%2C%22-829268773860757612%22%5D&pageHistory=0&fbzx=-829268773860757612"

params = Replace(params, "<NAME>", Range("A1").Value)
params = Replace(params, "<IG>", Range("A2").Value)
params = Replace(params, "<E>", Range("A3").Value)
  
' add a reference to Microsoft XML 6.0 (tools...reference...microsoft XML v6.0_

Dim http As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

http.Open "POST", url, False
http.setRequestHeader "content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
http.send params

End Sub
```

I received the error `Access Denied`. I changed the Internet Explorer Options: Internet Options Security > Custom Security Level > Miscellaneous > Access Data Sources Across Domains > Enable. This removed the error but my Google Form wasn't populated.

I have tried `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60` but this didn't populate the Google Form either.

Here is the [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Cbrn5BID2m4nlbm9imBu_etf5nWE3TGkYefu7DTsTRY/edit?usp=sharing) that contains the summary of all the responses. Here is the [Google Form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSejadFloQF5V69ZZ1fc1kManOZ_vMw8kq10-56ENroZ4c6xiw/viewform). My objective is to use Excel to automate the filling up of the Google Form. This code used to work before but I encountered the `Access Denied` error in files that used to work before. Could it be because of changes that Google must have implemented in their web-services?

I appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: The error message comes from Google  and not from  your system, And this is because The form is not publicly shared (not everyone can post the form ) and therefore Google authentication is required . to solve this just share your form to everyone . all of the above is apply to the spreadsheet  that in view only mode.

Comment: I have changed settings to "Anyone on the Internet with this link can edit" but the code doesn't seem to populate the google form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems that Google blocks requests without `User-Agent` so you need to add something like

```
http.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "my generic vba script"
```

before you send the parameters. Or you fake any existing user agent like

```
http.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2_1 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/7B405"
```

After adding that line the answer appears in the spreadsheet:

[image]

---

Use it like

```
http.Open "POST", url, False
http.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "my generic vba script"
http.setRequestHeader "content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
http.send params
```

As you can see in the screen recording below it works. I just copied your code added the reference to *Microsoft XML 6.0*, added the user agent line and run it.

[image]

Comment: I used the line of code you provided and replaced it in mine. However, I am unable to see my submission in the Spreadsheet. I'll try again with another device and confirm.

Comment: @BhaveshShaha Do not replace it. Use the line additionally to yours. See my edit.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. I'm really sorry but can you please help me out with the last leg? I am unable to replicate the same on my device. [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a-3YT5P965zMh-e-ofzSWdCVFVn_2BTN/view?usp=sharing) is a screen-recording.

Comment: That's strange as you can see the code works exactly as intended.

Comment: Thank you! I checked on another device and it works. Not sure why it isn't working in mine.

Answer (score 0):

you should set app settings to the values below:

[image: screen shot]

If any of these options are on, the use will be required to login with google account, this is why you are getting `Access Denied`

Comment: All the settings were already off. I have cross-checked it too.

Comment: try to send it as a GET API, like this: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSejadFloQF5V69ZZ1fc1kManOZ_vMw8kq10-56ENroZ4c6xiw/formResponse?entry.1880992192=NAME&entry.2125520249=IG&entry.1421191722=E&entry.1858469755=Option+1&entry.1858469755=Option+2&dlut=1632409237551&entry.1858469755_sentinel=&fvv=1&draftResponse=%5Bnull%2Cnull%2C%22-829268773860757612%22%5D&pageHistory=0&fbzx=-829268773860757612